# Angular how to access all the instance of a particular instance of component in the view

Tags: angular

My main page has many components inside it. These child components might contain a particular component say address component. 
How to access all instance of address component from the main page?

I think @ViewChildren give us only the direct children.These address components might be child of a child component.How to access them?

Comment: Cannot you do @ViewChildren(AddressComponent) addresses: QueryList<AddressComponent> ?

Comment: does it only give you the immediate child?  I need children below any level who are instance of address component

Comment: Without any code I can't say, but it is supposed to give a list of all instances, regardless the level.